# Setting A node only, to restricted mode. in AOAG instance

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I have an AOAG instance where the customer has access to the B node (read only) to pull reports. Every now and then we have to put the database on the A node in a restricted mode to apply updates or patches, this in turn sets the database on the B node in restricted mode causing the customers reports to fail. Is it possible to only set the A node databases in restricted mode, leaving the B node available for the customers read only user to access?

Answer (score 0):

> Every now and then we have to put the database on the A node in a
>   restricted mode to apply updates or patches, this in turn sets the
>   database on the B node in restricted mode causing the customers
>   reports to fail

This sounds like a database design where you can set a flag to lock users out of the database. This DML transaction would naturally replicate to the secondary. For things like SQL Agent jobs, you can conditionaly execute the job if it is or isn't the primary replica via [`sys.fn_hadr_is_paimary_replica`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-hadr-is-primary-replica-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) but this won't work to conditionally execute something like an `UPDATE` statement.

> Is it possible to only set the A node databases in restricted mode,
>   leaving the B node available for the customers read only user to
>   access?

Yes. Ideally you'd just run this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [your_database]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

But then you'd get an error like so:

> The operation cannot be performed on database "your_database" because
>   it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability
>   group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is
>   participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability
>   group.

Thus, some options are:

- Remove the secondary from the AG, apply the patches, readd the secondary and wait for it to catch up
- Restore another copy of the DB to a server for your customers to use during downtime